# Python mulitpart/formdata POST request within Zapier Code

Tags: python, webhooks, zapier

I'm currently working with Zapier to automate some tasks but I got stuck on the following :

I'm trying to send a POST request using the Zapier Webhooks containing a file. I could make it work trough postman as the API of Debitoor (that's where I am sending to) is pretty clear.

However, I can not make it work within Zapier Webhooks. I also tried to use Zapier Code (Python) as I can view the python code from the postman. But I am not familiar with that and might need some help to get it started.

1.) First of all, this is the API reference: https://developers.debitoor.com/api-reference#files

2.) I then used Postman with this code (Python requests)which was working :

```
import requests

url = "https://api.debitoor.com/api/files/v1"

querystring = {"token":"eyJ1c2VyIjoiNWE0NmVjYjUxOTE0ODEwMDFjMTkxYzZmIiwiYXBwIjoiNTdiMmZlMDkxZTkwMjQwZjAwNDZhNWEyIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlIjowLCIkZSI6MCwiJHQiOjE1MjE4NzAwNTQ1OTd9CsKRw5xbw5_DhHUWw5QJw4zDj8KnXsOaeMKA","fileName":"test.pdf"}

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Bildschirmfoto 2018-04-05 um 09.59.46 1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "716e7723-2dc1-6384-059d-960feb563443"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

3.) Tried to copy the code to Zapier Code, but I don't know how to implement the file. In Zapier I am triggering an inbound email to grab the attachment, which is then "hydrated". It looks like this :

```
hydrate|||.eJwtjMsOwiAUBf_lrosKNFDZu3Xh1hjC46KklTaFxDRN_11qXJ7JzFkhplxMcqijB8U5l7yT5wZCxMHrZN4Iqo4BMzTgXuh63eMCioruLKiobEwFU9FlmXb1WrX-Y-ZnBrX-Qj2NsSpzBfcV_o-3C2GUisPkwx7sj5D5UQpDmeMnwqW1pPWBE-OYJdYwdCJQT9sWtse2fQEK1Tjl:1eqY0S:s2Ek27XO54PVSm9q_mVMDN8o1uY|||hydrate
```

How do I connect the Python code to the hydrated file? I have no experience with files and could not find any useful help. Hope someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you update your question with what configuration you used for the outgoing webhook? I think that's the way we'll get this to work.

Comment: @xavdid do you mean the Zapier Webhook configuration?

Comment: Found a workaround : When I'm using a file from e.g. Dropbox instead that from an inbound Zapier Email the Zapier Webhook works just fine. If anyone has an idea how to work with this "hydrate|||..." file I'm happy to hear the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to import AWS S3 files to my API.

It turns out that Zapier hydrated my file just as described here.

Then I successfully extracted the content of my file and sent it to my API like this:

```py
import urllib.request

auth_token = input_data['auth_token'] # Authentication token for my API
csv_file = input_data['csv_file'] # The "hydrate|||..." variable: that's my S3 file
file_type = 'text/csv'

fp = urllib.request.urlopen(csv_file)
file_bytes = fp.read() # Binary content of my S3 file
fp.close()

url = 'http://my.api.com/importer/resource'
headers = {
  'accept': 'application/vnd.api-v1+json',
  'authorization': auth_token,
  'user-agent': 'Zapier'
}

files = {'csv_file': ('bulk_resources.csv', file_bytes, file_type, {'Expires': '0'})}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

return response.json()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?